doing embedding document in ollama with langchain always gets an error (400 Bad Request)
Always get error 400 Bad Request when i Trying to embedding document in ollama with langchain js.
here is my code
const embeddings = new OllamaEmbeddings({
  model: "orca-mini", 
  baseUrl: "http://localhost:11434",
});

const documents = new Document({
    pageContent: `Indonesia,[b] officially the Republic of Indonesia,[c] is a country in Southeast Asia and Oceania between the Indian and Pacific oceans. It consists of over 17,000 islands, including Sumatra, Java, Sulawesi, and parts of Borneo and New Guinea. Indonesia is the world's largest archipelagic state and the 14th-largest country by area, at 1,904,569 square kilometres (735,358 square miles). With over 280 million people, Indonesia is the world's fourth-most-populous country and the most populous Muslim-majority country. Java, the world's most populous island, is home to more than half of the country's population. Indonesia is a presidential republic with an elected legislature. It has 38 provinces, of which nine have special autonomous status. The country's capital, Jakarta, is the world's second-most-populous urban area. Indonesia shares land borders with Papua New Guinea, East Timor, and the eastern part of Malaysia, as well as maritime borders with Singapore, Vietnam, Thailand, the Philippines, Australia, Palau, and India. Despite its large population and densely populated regions, Indonesia has vast areas of wilderness that support one of the world's highest levels of biodiversity.`
});


const documentEmbeddings = await embeddings.embedDocuments([documents]);

console.log(documentEmbeddings);

and I get this error
file:///D:/USER/Documents/Programming/Generative%20AI/langchain/node_modules/@langchain/community/dist/embeddings/ollama.js:121
            throw new Error(`Request to Ollama server failed: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`);
                  ^

Error: Request to Ollama server failed: 400 Bad Request
    at OllamaEmbeddings._request (file:///D:/USER/Documents/Programming/Generative%20AI/langchain/node_modules/@langchain/community/dist/embeddings/ollama.js:121:19)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async RetryOperation._fn (D:\USER\Documents\Programming\Generative AI\langchain\node_modules\p-retry\index.js:50:12) {
  attemptNumber: 7,
  retriesLeft: 0
}

this error does not appear when I write the document like this
const documents = ["Hello World!", "Bye Bye"]
const documentEmbeddings = await embeddings.embedDocuments(documents);

console.log(documentEmbeddings);

and this error also does not appear when I embedding text.
so how to solve this error ?
